# Building shared libc.so for System V ABI under GNU ABI

Tags: gcc, gnu, libc, sysv

I need to build shared libc.so for System V ABI system under GNU ABI system from sources. I'm trying to build glibc2.16 if it is important.

My gcc compiler was built with the default --hash-style option set to "sysv". Every application built with it has System V ABI. Every, but not libc.

Tried to add C*FLAGS -Wl,--hash-style=sysv, but it didn't work. Configure was done, but making stopped with errors:

```
glibc cannot be compiled without optimization
```

I found that it is because of gcc options order. So, I decided to put necessary options by myself. Found --hash-style=both in Makeconfig and configure.in. Changed it to sysv. All libs (ld.so and other) were eventually built appropriate with System V. All except **libc.so**.

Do you know, how to build exactly libc.so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After different combinations of configuration options I got an answer.
The right configuration commands:

For x32 systems:

```
../configure --prefix=... --enable-kernel=2.4.0 --with-cpu=i686 --build=i686-unknown-linux-gnu CC="gcc -i686" CXX="g++ -i686"
```

For x64 systems:

```
../configure --prefix=... --enable-kernel=2.4.0 --with-cpu=i686 --build=i686-unknown-linux-gnu CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32"
```

And you need to export CFLAGS with the next value:

```
export CFLAGS="-mtune=native -O2 -pipe"
```